# What is cURL option parameters lifetime?

Tags: c, curl

I'm using cURL for the first time and while the documentation seems rather complete, I fail to see where I can find the required lifetime for the `curl_easy_setopt()` parameters.

Here is an example of what I mean:

```
char* str = strdup("my user agent");
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, str);
free(str);
```

Is `curl_handle` valid after the call to `free()` ?

Has `str` content been copied or is it still referenced directly by curl somewhere ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[From the official docs:](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html)

> Strings passed to libcurl as 'char *' arguments, are copied by the library; thus the string storage associated to the pointer argument may be overwritten after curl_easy_setopt() returns. Exceptions to this rule are described in the option details below.
>
> Before version 7.17.0, strings were not copied. Instead the user was forced keep them available until libcurl no longer needed them.

So if you use a recent version of libcurl, you can free the string immediately after setting it.

Comment: @ereOn also, you don't need that strdup.

Comment: I just wrote this code from scratch to illustrate my point. I actually take my string from a C++ `std::string`. Thanks for the advice though.